# Accessing nested data in stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, observable

I'm trying to update the data selection for stacked bars appended as below:

```
.data(series)
   .join('g')
   .attr("fill", d => color(d.key))  
   .selectAll("rect")
     .data(d => d)
     .join("rect") 
     .attr("class", "temp")
```

The code below updates the first key in the series data but how can I do a full update without iterating through each key?  There must be a more elegant solution to access the nested data and update selection.

```
         d3.selectAll(".temp")
             .data(series[0], d => d.data.code)  
             .order()
             .attr("x", d => x(d.data.code));
```

series data is like this
Array
{0, 1, data},
{0, 0.5, data} etc

Answer (score 0):

You can re-rerun the *selection*.join that created the whole stacked bar chart:

For example, if the code that renders the stacked bars is:

```js
 .data(series)
   .join('g')
   .attr("fill", d => color(d.key))  
   .selectAll("rect")
     .data(d => d)
     .join("rect") 
     .attr("class", "temp")
     .attr("x", d => x(d.data.code))
     .attr("y", ...)
     .attr("height", ...)
   ...
```

To change the data for the chart, all you need to do is re-rerun the same code with a different **series**. One way to achieve this is to put the code inside a function that accepts a **series**, and calling it again whenever there is a new series to render:

```js
function renderChart(series) {

 ...
   .data(series)
   .join('g')
   .attr("fill", d => color(d.key))  
   .selectAll("rect")
     .data(d => d)
     .join("rect") 
     .attr("class", "temp")
     .attr("x", d => x(d.data.code))
     .attr("y", ...)
     .attr("height", ...)
 ...

}

// To render the first series:
renderChart(series1)

// After some time or interaction, render the second series:
renderChart(series2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   This will work but I have run into problems with this approach due to circular referencing.   Mike Bostock's  Sortable Bar Chart is updated using the method below.   I'm looking for something similar for a stacked bar chart.  bar.data(data, d => d.name)
          .order()
        .transition(t)
          .delay((d, i) => i * 20)
          .attr("x", d => x(d.name));